# How to run a sql query in solr

Tags: php, sql, search, solr5

Ok now I have successfully install solr and index by database with following structure : DB_NAME - solr, Table - users

[image]

my db-data-config.xml file :

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/solr"
            user="root"
            password="" /> 
  <document>
    <entity name="users" query="select id,name from users;" />

    <field column="ID" name="id" /> 
    <field column="NAME" name="name" />

  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Which returns rows of database table users.

**Problem 1 :**

But what should I do if I want to search like 'Rakesh Shetty' and it should return result "Rakesh Vasant Shetty" ?

I have tried `<entity name="users" query="select id,name from users where name like '%Rakesh Shetty%' ;" />` but it returns empty result.

**Problem 2 :**

Also, how can I make this search query dynamic ? I mean there will be a form with search textbox and it should query to solr ? I am using php and solr 5.1.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try withe the below schema.

```
<schema name="simple" version="1.5"> 

<types> 
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>


<fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/> 
</types> 

<fields> 

<field name='id' type='int' required='true' indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
<field name='name' type='text' required='true' indexed="true" stored="true"/> 


</fields> 

<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey> 


<defaultSearchField>name</defaultSearchField> 
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator='OR' /> 

</schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer : [SOLR DIH USING CUSTOM VARIABLES](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Accessing_request_parameters)

So basically you need to pass custom variables to your DIH.xml file like

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/{collection_name}/dataimport?command=full-import&name=Rakesh&commit=true
```

And in DIH file you can access this variable with `${dataimporter.request.name}`, and use in your DIH query.

eg ,

```
 <entity name="users" query="select id,name from users where name ='${dataimporter.request.name}' ;" />
```

And for your **dynamic search** refer link below

http://solr.pl/en/2010/10/18/solr-and-autocomplete-part-1/

Comment: I have put your example query on db-data-config.xml file and run the url http://localhost:8983/solr/search/dataimport&command=full-import&clean=false&commit=true&name=Rakesh but it throws error `Problem accessing /solr/search/dataimport&command=full-import&clean=false&commit=true&name=Rakesh. Reason:

    Not Found`

Comment: @RakeshShetty append this to your URI ,  -->  &name=Rakesh, above one is just for example  sake

Comment: ok when I written `?` instead of `&` like this `http://localhost:8983/solr/search/dataimport?commit=true&name=Rakesh` then it shows me the result `<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Time Elapsed">0:0:14.355</str>
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2015-05-12 14:45:40</str>
<str name="Full Import failed">2015-05-12 14:45:40</str>
</lst>`

Comment: @rtakesh , check my edit... use your existing solr full import query , just you need to append your own custom variables.

Comment: check my edit for data.xml file , you need to put under quaotation the name in select query

Comment: I run this url http://localhost:8983/solr/search/dataimport?command=full-import&name=Rakesh&commit=true and I got the response like this :- `<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Time Elapsed">0:0:2.672</str>
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2015-05-12 14:54:11</str>
<str name="Full Import failed">2015-05-12 14:54:12</str>
</lst>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77588/discussion-between-anirban-n-and-rakesh-shetty).